# ¿Como se puede solucionar el error "first definited here"?

Tags: c

```
#include <genesis.h>

int main(u16 hard)
{

}
```

Yo en el anterior código que hice puse la misma base pero no se porque ya no lo acepta, salta un mensaje llamado "first definited here", si lo preguntan estoy usando codeblocks, más específicamente su idioma predefinido "c", soy bastante novato y de seguro es un error muy fácil de solucionar, si alguien sabe contestar, me seria de gran ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso del lenguaje C, `main` puede definirse de dos formas diferentes:

- Sin parámetros:

  ```
  int main()
  ```
- Con **dos** parámetros. El primero permite saber cuántos argumentos ha recibido el programa en el momento de ejecutarse, el segundo parámetro es una lista con los argumentos:

  ```
  int main(int argc, char** argv)
  ```

En tu caso, la función `main` no coincide con ninguna de estas dos opciones y de ahí el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por solucionarme el error, como ya ves, soy bastante novato en el mundo de la creación de videojuegos.

Comment: Para definir una función sin parámetros en C se debe usar el *void*: `int main(void)`.